# Posting JSON Date to MVC 4 action webapi

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to post JSON date to MVC 4 action in webapi controller.

Time is now **22:05 +1 GMT**.

Javascript say using: **new Date() - Wed Nov 28 2012 22:05:46 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)**

That's gets JSONized when posting to server with: **ko.toJSON({date:new Date()}) which gets: "{"date":"2012-11-28T21:06:50.273Z"}"**

And thats what I get at server 21:06, but it is 22:06. MVC 4 is using JSON.net, so what am I missing?

webapi/action:

```
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]VM vm)
{
     vm.date = 21:06 ????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateTime's kind on the server is UTC, and when using ToLocalTime() I get the desired result.